How can I start a docker container via an independent docker container?
I have a manager container that I would like to give the ability to start an adjudicator container N times. The adjudicator container does not persist so when it runs, it completes its tasks and then exits. How can I give the manager the ability to start this process over for a set amount of times?
I've seen people talk similar issues with a solution involving mounting docker socket or docker in docker but I'm fairly new to docker so I don't entirely understand what those entail.

Use the Docker socket method, which is simpler than Docker-in-Docker (DinD) that you currently comparing...But you must consider the Security ... Mounting the Docker socket provides the manager container full control over the host's Docker daemon

@Bhargav Do you have a step by step process to using the docker socket method? Sorry, I'm very new to Docker so I'm a bit confused as to how to accomplish this.

You have to check "Docker-outside-of-docker" (DooD) to allow the manager container to control the docker environment.
Try following thing.
1- Mount the docker socket(/var/run/docker.sock) from the host when you run the manager container and the Command is
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name manager-container your-manager-image
*Just make sure Docker CLI is installed in your manager container.
You can also check Docker-in-Docker (DinD)

When I run that command I get this problem:
docker: Error response from daemon: mkdir C:\Program Files\Git\var: Access is denied.
Do you know how I can get around this?
Also, once I mount the docker socket do you know how I can control how many times it starts up the adjudicator container?

Obligatory reminder that, if you can run any Docker command at all, you can docker run -v /:/host -u root ..., bind-mounting the host's filesystem into the new container, and trivially take over the host.  You can't limit what can be done via the Docker socket (or limit the number of times it can be invoked).
